# AWS S3 - Putting Objects and Getting Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been using s3.php and the function putObjectFile() to put objects onto S3. But now I see this is depreciated. I've been looking around at the best class to use going forward.

What would be the best AWS Class to use for putting and getting objects?

Also if you have some basic examples or a page with examples of how to do these 2 functions it would be great.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [putObject](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#putObject) method which is the replacement for `putObjectFile`:

```
<?php

    // Simple PUT:
    if (S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($file), $bucket, $uri, S3::ACL_PRIVATE)) {
        echo "File uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to upload file.";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend provides good component for S3 operation

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html#zend.service.amazon.s3.objects

You can google it to get lot of PHP examples.